# ASP.NET configuration throws "Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Web, Version=6.3.2.0,..." when trying to add a new user

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, configuration

OK, this is a little odd. Why is the ASP.NET configuration utility looking for MySql? I had tried using MySql 3 or 4 iterations earlier in another project, but have not tried to use it in this project that I know of.

Visual Studio 2010, .NET 4, ASP.NET MVC 2.0 project with web service references in lieu of a local model (web service using SQL Server Express 2008 R2). I am using SQL Express for the credentials store from the MVC project.

I checked the web.config for any reference to MySql, deleted all instances of MySql from my computer, and spent 20 minutes looking for any other leftover debris, and I still get this error.  WTF?

Dave

Here is the complete stack trace from the exception.  All I am trying to do is create a second user in aspnetdb.  I aded the first user from the MVC 2 application (using the register link)...

Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Web, Version=6.3.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type) at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName) at System.RuntimeType.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) at System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) at System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, XmlNode node, Boolean checkAptcaBit, Boolean ignoreCase)

As far as I can tell, I am not responsible for any of that.  So I say again, WTF?

Comment: Have you tried clearing your the files (ASP.Net cached files) in this folder windowsdir\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files

Comment: I had not, but I just tried it with no luck.  Also cleared out the temporary files for v4...

Comment: You might have a look at my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28911096/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-mysql-web-version-6-8-3-0/29148048#29148048

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the full exception stack trace. It will show you which method is trying to load this library. Then remove the referenced assembly containing the offending method from your project.

Comment: I can't verify this (something I deleted from the temp directory has now caused me more problems), but I believe the stack trace was all internal Microsoft assemblies, none of my code.  I'll dig into it tomorrow...

Comment: I cleared up my other problem, and this one still exists.  I posted the full stack trace, but I see nothing in there that gives me a clue.