# Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Web, Version=6.8.3.0

Tags: asp.net

**ASP.NET** configuration throws `Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Web, Version=6.8.3.0,0,…` when trying to add a new user

```
<add name="MySQLMembershipProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" 
    connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
    enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" 
    applicationName="/" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Clear" 
    maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" passwordAttemptWindow="10"    
    passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You might install/reinstall MySQL Connector or try the steps below:

**1)** Go to machine.Config.

for 32 bit Operating System:
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework[version]\config\machine.config

for 64 bit Operating System:
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64[version]\config\machine.config

**2)** Then remove or comment out these lines below:

```
<add name="MySQLRoleProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLRoleProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.7.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="/"/>

<add name="MySQLMembershipProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.7.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" applicationName="/" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Clear" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
```